# Ubuntu Equivalent to BSD Ports?

Tags: installation, command-line, install-from-source

Is there an Ubuntu equivalent to the BSD Ports system? I realize that the Linux and Ubuntu culture tends to install new software from binaries, but having used BSD ports within both BSD and Mac OS X I find it very simple and elegant and the idea of compiling from source on demand, with all dependencies figured out for you, is very powerful.

Comment: Not sure about Ubuntu, but Gentoo is using a system like the one you are describing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most linux distributions, Ubuntu included, distribute packages as binaries. Unless you have a very specific need, IMO, building from source is over rated.

IMO, if you wish to compile from source, you are better off using [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/)or [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1).

You can, of course, achieve the same thing with Ubuntu by building from source. You should avoid installing packages outside of apt as much as possible.

[here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system) is a nice overview of why (fedora wiki).

So what you would do on ubuntu is download the source code from the ubuntu repositories, make any modifications needed, build a package, and install it with apt (dpkg). Doing so is poorly supported, and as with LFS and Gentoo you will need to do a bit of reading.

The documentation is a bit scattered.

### Enable the source repositories

You need to enable the source repositories to download the source code.

[image: source repositories]

See [Ubuntu wiki repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) for details.

### apt-build

apt-build will build from source and is probably the best way of achieving what you want on Ubuntu or Debian (or Mint ...)

```
sudo apt-get install apt-build auto-apt
```

Configure your options

```
dpkg-reconfigure apt-build
```

You probably want to use -jx where x = number of CPU +1

To prevent your compiled packages / libs from being over written, put these options in `/etc/apt/preferences`

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=apt-build
Pin-Priority: 990
```

Build

```
apt-build install <package>
```

see [man apt-build](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/apt-build.1.html)

### apt-get

apt-get will download the source and install dependencies (binaries)

```
# build-deb installs the dependencies (binary)
sudo apt-get build-dep <package>

apt-get source <package>
```

You can then build and package with any number of tools.

See:

[Ubuntu Wiki Easy Compiling](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

The page on compiling a kernel has more details and alternate options (fakeroot,

[Ubuntu wiki compile kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile)

That should get you started ;)